# I want to save object instead of array in reactjs with laravel api

Tags: reactjs, arrays, laravel, api, multi-select

When I save a multi-select, I experted the transLanguage to be an true form object, or anything else like
["ak", "an", "lu", "am", "as"]
(Save as Ditto mark form)

But I can just save the transLanguage as an array like: ['ak', 'an', 'lu', 'am', 'as']
(As Apostrophe form)

So what should I change? This is my Reactjs code:

```
import '../../css/style.css';
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState, useSelector } from "react";
import { ajaxCallGetUrlDemo, ajaxCallPost } from "../libs/base";
import Select from 'react-select'
import { Const_Libs } from "../libs/Const_Libs";
import languagesList from "./languageList/country";
import { get } from 'jquery';

const ModalAddNgonNgu = (props) => {
const { handleGetLanguage } = props;
const [langName, setLangName] = useState("");
const [mainLang, setMainLang] = useState("");
const [titleLang, setTitleLang] = useState("");
const [describeLang, setDescribeLang] = useState("");
const [authorLang, setAuthorLang] = useState("");
const [rateLang, setRateLang] = useState("");
const [reviewsLang, setReviewsLang] = useState("");
const [translateList, setTranslateList] = useState();

const mainLangOptions = [
    { value: 'vi', label: 'Vietnamese' },
    { value: 'en', label: 'English' },
    { value: 'zh', label: 'Chinese' },
    { value: 'ja', label: 'Japanese' },
    { value: 'de', label: 'German' },
];
const handleMainLang=(e)=>{
    setMainLang(e.value);
}

const handleTransList=(e)=>{
    setTranslateList(Array.isArray(e)?e.map(x=>x.value):[]);
}


const handleSubmit = () => {
    let arr = [{
        nameLanguage: langName,
        mainLanguage: mainLang,
        titleLanguage: titleLang,
        descriptionLanguage: describeLang,
        authorLanguage: authorLang,
        rateLanguage: rateLang,
        reviewsLanguage: reviewsLang,
        transLanguage: translateList
    }]
    console.log(arr);
    resetData();
    props.saveLang(arr);
}

const resetData = () => {
    setLangName("");
    setMainLang("");
    setTitleLang("");
    setDescribeLang("");
    setAuthorLang("");
    setRateLang("");
    setReviewsLang("");
    setTranslateList();
}


return (
    <>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModalAddNgonNgu" style={{ fontSize: '14px' }}>
            Thêm
        </button>
        <div>
            <div className="modal fade" id="myModalAddNgonNgu">
                <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style={{ minWidth: '700px' }}>
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h4 className="modal-title">Thêm ngôn ngữ</h4>
                            <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            <form>
                                <div className="col">
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Tên ngôn ngữ</label>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                            placeholder="Nhập tên ngôn ngữ...."
                                            // value={langName}
                                            onChange={(e) => setLangName(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Tiêu đề</label>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                            placeholder="Nhập tiêu đề...."
                                            // value={titleLang}
                                            onChange={(e) => setTitleLang(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Mô tả</label>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                            placeholder="Nhập mô tả...."
                                            // value={describeLang}
                                            onChange={(e) => setDescribeLang(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Tác giả</label>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                            placeholder="Nhập tác giả (VD: Author)"
                                            // value={authorLang}
                                            onChange={(e) => setAuthorLang(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Đánh giá</label>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                            placeholder="Nhập đánh giá (VD: Rate)"
                                            // value={rateLang}
                                            onChange={(e) => setRateLang(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Lượt đánh giá</label>
                                        <input type="text"
                                            className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                            placeholder="Nhập lượt đánh giá (VD: reviews)"
                                            // value={reviewsLang}
                                            onChange={(e) => setReviewsLang(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col">
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Ngôn ngữ chính</label>
                                        {/* <select placeholder='Select' className={`col-12 o-languages`} onChange={(e)=>handleMainLang(e)}>
                                            {
                                                mainLangOptions.map((ml) => (
                                                    <option value={ml.value}>{ml.label}</option>
                                                )
                                                )
                                            }
                                        </select> */}
                                         <Select 
                                            onChange={handleMainLang}
                                            options={mainLangOptions}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Những ngôn ngữ dịch</label>
                                        {/* <select multiple className={`col-12 o-languages`} onChange={(e) =>handleTransList(e)}>
                                            {
                                                languagesList.map((lgl) => (
                                                    <option value={lgl.value}>{lgl.label}</option>
                                                )
                                                )
                                            }
                                        </select> */}
                                        <Select 
                                            onChange={handleTransList}
                                            isMulti
                                            isSearchable={true}
                                            options={languagesList}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
);
}

export default ModalAddNgonNgu;
```

Comment: what should you change..... to do **what**?

Comment: sorry, I think my problem here is when I send the api, the transLanguage send the wrong type: ['ak', 'an', 'lu', 'am', 'as']. But I need to send the type like  ["ak", "an", "lu", "am", "as"]. Do you have any idea?

Comment: edit the question and write the **expected response** and what you are getting.

Comment: You have an Array.map() in your setTranslatelist. According to the documentation, .map() returns an array of elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I edited the question, and I think I should change the handleTransList, right?